# Reading and understanding ternary operators?

Tags: java, ternary

I'm trying to understand ternary operators and don't see an example with return statements.

```
 return (next == null) ? current : reversing(current,next);
```

How would you write that without the ternary operator? Is it just:

```
if (next == null) { 

} else { 
  return (current,next);
```

Comment: *don't see an example with return statements* why would that affect the workings?

Comment: see documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/2806/ternary-operator#t=201703021604546865206

Answer (score 4):

Your version:

- Completely removes one of the return values
- Completely ignores the function call in the other

```java
if (next == null) {
    return current;
} else {
    return reversing(current,next);
}
```

That said, the `else` isn't necessary. I'd put the early return on `null` on its own:

```java
if (next == null) {
    return current;
}

return reversing(current, next);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return (next == null) ? current : reversing(current, next);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (next == null) {
    return current;
} else {
    return reversing(current, next);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. You would write as follows

```
if (next == null) {
    return current;
} else {
    return reversing(current, next);
}
```